# Create new unique field in table CustTable

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, morph-x

I'm working on a project around dynamics AX 2012, and I want to add some fields in CustTable.

I want to add a unique field that has 11 characters and consists of 4 digits

1: 1 character for sex

2: 2 character for year of birth

3: 2 character for month of birth

4: 6 character  this character should be auto-increment

How can i complete this , and when i create the new form how can I implement this field automatically?

Thank you

```
----------------------------post update------------------------------------------
```

Thank you for reply,

The field that I want create is composed of  10 character's divided into 4 components(segment/digit)

What  i want is: how to create the unique field  (cust_Id for example)  that consists of 4 segment.For example if i want create new customer , in form ,I seized sex & date birth and other .

I want to create this field :

```
1. Gender (1 digit) 

          •1 for men 

          •2 for women 

2. Year of birth (2 digits) 

          • The last two digits of the year 

          • Example: 78 for 1978 

3. Month of birth (2 digits) 

4. Order number (5 digits)  auto increment
```

Global example:

```
men     22/03/1990   00001
```

When  I submit  the form  the field must contain this value :  1-90-03-00001  that is the unique identifier of new customer inserted generated automatically.

next record :

```
women   30/12/1994   00002       =>   value :  0-94-12-00002
```

I did some research, I found that I can do that by Number Sequence scope or segment, 
thank you

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean by "and when i create new form how can i implement this field automatically?"?

Answer (score 2):

To add a field to a table, have a look at [How to: Create Tables [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa882181.aspx), "Add Fields to a Table".

To add a field to a form, have a look at [How to: Add Fields to a Details Form [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528514.aspx).

That being said, I strongly suggest to not create a field that contains several bits of information. Instead you could take a look at the DirPerson table that contains fields for gender, month of birth and year of birth and try to figure out how to make them available on the customer.

Comment: You may need a new number sequence as well, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608474.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish by creating a number sequence, but that would be a little hectic solution, since your requirement is unique, you should go for a unique and simpler solution,

if i were you,i would add a text field in the CustTable, and add multiple drop down controls on my form(for gender, DOB etc) each bound by an enum  , and when the form submits take those returned values and format them according to ur requirement ( 1-90-03-00001)

for the last auto increment number, you can fetch the last inserted record, then split it with "-" and increment the last number by one.

Comment: Can you explain me step by step how can i produce for your approach , i can use this 1900300001 without  "-". Thank you

Comment: Step 1 - Create a simple text field in CustTable
step 2 - Create Enum for gender then bind it to the drop down control on the form, and for DOB just use the calender control on the form
Step 3 - When the user submits the form, you will have gender from Gender drop down,and a date from the calender control,Split the Date with "/" that will return u a container with all the split values

Comment: Step 4 - Get the last inserted record from CustTable (CreatedDate field will give u the last inserted record), split that record with "-", that will give u all the splitted values,take the last value (00001,00002 etc) increment it by one, then merge it with values you got in step 3 like so(Gender value-Year of Birth-Month of birth-00003), then insert it back with the new record